# package or namespace load failed for 'SequentialTranches'

Tags: r, ubuntu-14.04, opencpu

I have installed custom package 'SequentialTranches' in my local VM (IP: 192.168.1.215). But this package is not showing in
http://192.168.1.215/ocpu/library/base/R/

I use the above URL to connect from my code.

When I access the following URL it shows "package or namespace load failed for 'SequentialTranches'".
URL: http://192.168.1.215/ocpu/library/SequentialTranches/R

Information page http://192.168.1.215/ocpu/library/SequentialTranches/info shows the information correctly.

OS: Ubuntu 14.04.1 LTS
openCPU version: 1.5.6
R version: 3.2.5

Please help me to solve the issue.

Answer (score 0):

First of all you are running a very old version of R and OpenCPU. I highly recommend upgrading if possible.

Does your package show up in `http://192.168.1.215/ocpu/library`? Make sure to refresh your page (CTRL+R in the browser) to make sure you're not looking at a cached response.

To debug why your package isn't loading, have a look at the log files. The [pdf server manual](https://opencpu.github.io/server-manual/opencpu-server.pdf) explains which log files are relevant to look at.

Comment: I have upgraded OS to Ubuntu 16.04, R version to 3.4.2 and openCPU version to 2.0.
Now "SequentialTranches" listed in http://192.168.1.215/ocpu/library

But "SequentialTranches" is not listing in
http://192.168.1.215/ocpu/library/base/R/

I use the above URL to connect from my code.Have any configurations to correct this issue?

Comment: The `/ocpu/library/base/R` endpoint lists functions in the R `base` package. You need to call out to `/ocpu/library/SequentialTranches/R`.

Comment: Is there any option to add "SequentialTranches" to R base package?

Answer (score 0):

I have upgraded OS to Ubuntu 16.04, R version to 3.4.2 and openCPU version to 2.0.
Now "SequentialTranches" listed in http://192.168.1.215/ocpu/library

But "SequentialTranches" is not listing in
http://192.168.1.215/ocpu/library/base/R/

I use the above URL to connect from my code.Have any configurations to correct this issue?